# Ошибка таймаута при отправке WSDL C#

Tags: c#, wsdl

При попытки отправиь с клиента вылетает ошибка таймаута:

> Тайм-аут канала запроса во время ожидания ответа после истечения
> 00:09:59.9843647. Увеличьте значение времени тайм-аута, передаваемое
> вызову при Request или увеличьте значение SendTimeout в Binding.
> Время, назначенное для выполнения этой операции, может быть составной
> частью более длинного тайм-аута.. Во время запроса HTTP в
> "http://127.0.0.1/Service.svc" было превышено выделенное время
> ожидания для 00:10:00. Время, выделенное для выполнения этой операции,
> может быть частью более длительного тайм-аута.. Запрос был прерван:
> Время ожидания операции истекло.

Хотя по факту не прошло и 1 минуты.
В коде пробовал указать таймаут

```
var time = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
client.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = time;
client.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = time;
client.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = time;
client.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = time;
```

Ничего не изменилось. Подскажите куда копать?

Comment: wsdl - это файл, который получают клиенты, чтобы знать, как общаться с SOAP-сервисом. Не понимаю, зачем вам с клиента отправлять WSDL куда-либо

Comment: Укажите на стороне сервиса в секции `binding` файла конфигурации все таймауты, затем сгенерируйте клиент для этого сервиса через VisualStudio. После чего не меняйте биндинги у клиента - все должно работать.

Comment: мне не доступна сторона сервера. Все что я могу, это по ссылки сгенерить у себя клиента через VS.

Comment: Или я не правильно вас понял?

Comment: Я говорю про сторону сервиса (не сервера). У вас по данному адресу `http://127.0.0.1/Service.svc` доступен сервис. Судя по адресу сервиса, он запущен локально на вашей машине. Значит, вероятнее всего, вы сами его разворачивали. Найдите, где этот сервис лежит физически, найдите там `web.config`, там должна быть секция `binding`